# Datatype size for number of bits

Tags: c++

So I have the following function:

```
static int calcDTSize( int depth )
{
    if ( depth <= 8 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if ( depth <= 16 )
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if ( depth <= 32 )
    {
        return 4;
    }
    if ( depth <= 64 )
    {
        return 8;
    }

    throw std::exception( "Invalid bit count" );
}
```

Which calculates the size of datatype required for the specified number of bits. Originally I just had:

```
return ( (int) std::ceil( (double) depth / 8.0 ) );
```

However, on most machines that I know of, there isn't a datatype which is 3 bytes long.

I'm sure there must be a neater way of doing the calculation without the if statements but I can't think how.

Anyone got a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide by 8 and round up to closest power of 2.

Considering that the input is limited and the information is completely static, I would however probably put it in a look up array and do

```
if (depth <= 64)
    return lut[depth];

throw std::exception( "Invalid bit count" );
```

---

If you don't want 64 entries in the lut, you could do something like

```
static int calcDTSize( int depth )
{
  static int lut[] = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8 };

  if (depth <= 64)
    return lut[(depth - 1 >> 3) + 1];

  throw std::exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (int) std::pow(2.0, std::ceil((double)depth / 8.0) - 1)
```

Since they are all powers of 2 you just find the exponent with the division.

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
static int calcDTSize( int depth )
{
  const int d = depth / 8;

  if (d < 1) || (d & (d - 1) != 0) || (d > 8)
    throw std::exception("Invalid bit count");

  return d;
}
```

Where:

```
const int d = depth / 8;
```

Simply gives the result of the integer division.

And where:

```
if (d < 1) || (d & (d - 1) != 0) || (d > 8)
```

Check if `d` is between 1 and 8, and is a power of 2.

The trick is that the `d & (d - 1)` expression returns `0` for all powers of two, and non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This code test for (1) values greater than maximum size, (2) invalid 3 byte data size and (3) values not multiple of 8:

```
static int calcDTSize( int depth)
{
    if ( (depth <= 64) && (depth != 24) && (depth % 8 == 0) )
        return depth / 8;
    else
        throw std::exception("Invalid bit count");
}
```